# Defining a timeout on boost async_receive_from

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I have a boost socket on which I defined an asynchronous receive :

```
void recv() {
  boost_socket->async_receive_from(
    boost::asio::buffer(buffer, MTU),
    endpoint,
    [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes) {
      // Treatment...
      if (event) {
        Component::recv(handler);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

But if no event is coming to this socket (no packet on the socket), I would be stuck in the lambda method...

Is there a way of defining a timeout on this recv ?

Comment: Pick a question. "Defining a timeout on boost `async_receive_from`"? Or "Is there a way of defining a timeout on this `recv`?". These are completely unrelated, different questions

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of defining a timeout on this recv ?

If the call to `Component::recv` is itself an `asio`-operation, you may define a deadline timer that cancels the read operation upon timeout. You can find an example in the [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp) (example/cpp03/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp).

Otherwise, you may use std::future:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, &Component::recv, handler);
if(fut.wait_for(500ms) == std::future_status::timeout) {
   // timed out
}
```

Comment: It is not a asio-operation :( Should I encapsulate it with asio ?

Comment: @klaus You may use `std::future` instead.

Comment: Assuming that Component::recv is threadsafe. Note that discarding the future does *not* "cancel" the `recv` operation.

Comment: Thank you. This is c++ 14 required, isn’t it ? If I am using c++ 11, is there something else ?

Comment: Let's say, I have the following treatment inside my lambda : B->f(arg) and I want to use your async on this, if I try : `auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, &B->f, arg);` I have an error "ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function"... do you know why ?

Comment: @klaus The syntax would be `auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, &YourClass::f, B, arg);`

Comment: @Jodocus Thank you ! It compiles \o/ (now, I have to test it...)

Comment: @klaus Note that sehe's point still stays valid. The operation will be still running, you cannot stop it if it is blocking. So when data is available, it will be read and you have no way to get notified if you lose the reference to the future object. Keep that in mind.

Comment: @Jodocus ok... and last question ! If I want to define the std::async on the `boost_socket->async_receive_from`, is it possible ? (because among the arguments of the async_receive_from function, I have a lambda...)

Comment: @klaus This makes absolutely no sense. `async_receive_from` immediately returns, it is already asynchronous.

Comment: @klaus I know but why the hell async_receive_from is not able to take a timeout as argument ? :(

Comment: @klaus Because it is not the job of `async_*` functions to get a timeout. The waiting thread decides on how long to wait. I gave you the boost doc link where you can see how to make proper timeouts in asio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161183/discussion-between-klaus-and-jodocus).